# How to get HTML source with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get HTML source with JavaScript:

Why this does not work?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function MyGetHTML()
      {
        $.get("www.example.com/test1.html", function(data){
          return data;
        });
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  test 30.9.2015
  <script>
    alert(MyGetHTML());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's an async ajax call. You won't get response as soon as you invoke it.

Comment: @SterlingArcher It's only a test.

Comment: Note you can only use Ajax for sites on *other domains* that explicitly allow you to do so. (Same Origin Policy)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You can read more about it here: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

Comment: There are two issues here: You don't seem to be aware of how Ajax works and you are trying to "load" a third-party domain. Both of these have been covered on Stack Overflow extensively. In your actual code, are you planning to get the source of "external" pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Below, i'm assuming that you need to get content from filen IN your source, **from the same origin of your page**.)*

Your code doen't works because the the `return` of your `MyGetHTML` method is the get request itself, and the `success` callback of your request returns the `data`.

You could do:

```
function MyGetHTML(){
    $.get("www.example.com/test1.html", function(data){
      //alert(data);
      //or use console.log() instead.
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

And then

```
MyGetHTML(); //This will log your data after the succesfull request.
```

Further reading: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

### Hint on your use case:

A simple tutorial [from Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855) on making simple ajax requests.

With pure JS:

```
load('test.html', function(xhr) {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
});

function load(url, callback) {
        var xhr;

        if(typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else {
            var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0", 
                            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
                            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", 
                            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
                            "Microsoft.XmlHttp"]

             for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
                try {
                    xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                    break;
                }
                catch(e){}
             } // end for
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness;

        function ensureReadiness() {
            if(xhr.readyState < 4) {
                return;
            }

            if(xhr.status !== 200) {
                return;
            }

            // all is well  
            if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
                callback(xhr);
            }           
        }

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send('');
    }
```

Or with jquery library

```
$('#container').load('test.html');
```

Comment: Maybe add a note that this still won't help getting the source of *external* pages?

Answer (score -2):

Because you're returning to the `get` not the function itself. Try like this:

```
 function MyGetHTML()
      {

        var datum = '';

        $.get("www.example.com/test1.html", function(data){
          datum = data;
        });

       return datum;
      }
```

Comment: $.get is asynchronous.  once you call MyGetHTML(), it always return ''.